# WKWebView fullscreen instead of frame?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, webkit, wkwebview

I am new to Swift 3.0 and I need some help...

I am trying to create a frame with should display a website. The website should not fill the entire view but just the frame. Every time I start the App, the website fills the entire screen and not just the frame... :(

This is my code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let myURL = URL(string: "https://www.google.com/")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
    }
}
```

What I want:

[image]

What I get:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add constraints (anchor) for webview with equal padding.

Try this with storyboard layout:

Remove `loadView()` code from your file:

[image]

Or Try this programatically:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class WebKitController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let myURL = URL(string: "https://www.google.com/")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        setupWKWebViewConstraints()
        webView.load(myRequest)
    }

    // add constraints to your web view
    func setupWKWebViewConstraints() {

        let paddingConstant:CGFloat = 30.0

        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: paddingConstant).isActive = true
        webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -paddingConstant).isActive = true
        webView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: paddingConstant).isActive = true
        webView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -paddingConstant).isActive = true
    }

}
```

Comment: Now it's just a black screen... :/

Comment: There must be some kind of error in my project. When I try the same code in another project it works as it should.... But thank you very much for your help, I appreciate that very much :)

Comment: You had a problem with `loadView()` function, that might have taken/copied from one of the stack over flow post, right? Remove `loadView()` from your code and add constraint, will work.

Comment: Deleted View Controller and created a new one: now it works! :)

Comment: I was looking for how to programmatically set `WKWebView` initialized via `@IBOutlet` to full screen. Your code helped me. I have just used 0.0 for padding :) Because `WKWebView` via `WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())` is automatically at full screen but `UIView.transition()` does not work without `@IBOutlet`.